# Functional equation $f\left(\frac{x+3f(x)}{4}\right)=x$

Tags: functional-equations

> If $f$ is a real valued function defined on the set of real numbers and $f$ is strictly increasing on its domain and the following holds:
> $$f\left(\frac{x+3f(x)}{4}\right)=x$$
> for all real $x$, then prove that $f(x)=x$ for all real $x$.

I've proven that $f(0)=0$ and that $f$ is bijective but I don't see anything else.

Comment: The surjective part is obvious so combining it with the fact that f is strictly increasing we get bijectivity.
Thus f has a unique root.
If that root s not 0 from the relation above we get that $x/4$ is also a root which is impossible as f is bijective.

Comment: Hint: Fix $a$ and suppose that $f(a)>a$. Then $\frac{a+3f(a)}{4}>a$. But $f$ is strictly increasing, so...

Comment: You can use the same trick to prove that the only linear map from R \to R is identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $x$ and $f(x)$ have the same sign. Now we proceed by contradiction.

Assume that for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) > x$;
then $$\frac{x + 3f(x)}{4} > x $$
Now because $f$ is strictly increasing, this imples
$$f\bigg(\frac{x+3f(x)}{4}\bigg) > f(x)$$
$$x > f(x) $$
Hence we get a contradiction.

PS: For the initial steps, read the comment of the OP to his question.